# Problem with saveing json list to custom model list

Tags: c#, json, rest

I can deserializable one json object but i have a problem when REST API send list of json object. My model

```
 public class ToDoItem
    {  
        public string AdId { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string CategoryGroup { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
        public string Voivodeship { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Negotiable { get; set; }
        public string AdType { get; set; }
    }
```

and fragment of method witch save to `List<ToDoItem>`

```
response = await client.GetStringAsync("myUrl");
                    
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
{
     adList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoItem>>(response);
}
```

and example of json format, i have a problem with `adList` without that everything work

```
adList:
    [
     {parameter},
     {parameter}
    ]
```

Comment: Your  "example of json format" is not valid JSON.

Comment: provide a code sample that can be used to reproduce the issue.  Also, it is not clear what you mean by "I have a problem".  If you are getting an exception or data is not populating, provide the exception info and\or clarify what problem you are having.